# Connect Apollo with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, async-await, graphql, apollo, next.js

I want to connect my Apollo server with my mongoDB. I know there are many examples out there, but I get stuck at the async part and did not found a solution or example for that (that's strange, am I completly wrong?)

I started with the example from next.js https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client .
But the mongodb integration is missing.

## My code

**pages/api/graphql.js**

```js
    import {ApolloServer} from 'apollo-server-micro';
    import {schema} from '../../apollo/schema';

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({schema});

    export const config = {
        api: {
            bodyParser: false
        }
    };

    export default apolloServer.createHandler({path: '/api/graphql'});
```

**apollo/schema.js**

```js
    import {makeExecutableSchema} from 'graphql-tools';
    import {typeDefs} from './type-defs';
    import {resolvers} from './resolvers';

    export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers
    });
```

**apollo/resolvers.js**

```js
    const Items = require('./connector').Items;
    export const resolvers = {
        Query: {
            item: async (_parent, args) => {
                const {id} = args;
                const item = await Items.findOne(objectId(id));
                return item;
            },
            ...
        }
    }
```

**apollo/connector.js**

```js
    require('dotenv').config();
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    const password = process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD;
    const username = process.env.MONGO_USER;
    const uri = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@example.com`;

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
    const db = await client.db('databaseName')
    const Items = db.collection('items')

    module.exports = {Items}
```

So the problem is the `await` in `connector.js`. I have no idea how to call this in an async function or how to provide the MongoClient on an other way to the resolver. If I just remove the `await`, it  returns – obviously – an pending promise and can't call the function `.db('databaseName')` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we're still a ways off from having [top-level await](https://github.com/babel/proposals/issues/44).

You can delay running the rest of your code until the Promise resolves by putting it inside the `then` callback of the Promise.

```
async function getDb () {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri)
  return client.db('databaseName')
}

getDb()
  .then(db => {
    const apollo = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      context: { db },
    })
    apollo.listen()
  })
  .catch(e => {
    // handle any errors
  })
```

Alternatively, you can create your connection the first time you need it and just cache it:

```
let db

const apollo = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async () => {
    if (!db) {
      try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri)
        db = await client.db('databaseName')
      catch (e) {
        // handle any errors
      }
    }
    return { db }
  },
})
apollo.listen()
```

Comment: Thank you! the second example did it! 
the first one is not possible inside the `page/api` folder of next.js. Because I have to export the ApolloServer in an synchron way and can't wait for the DB to connect in the first step. 

But the second one ist very nice and works 

Comment: The first pattern could still work, but you would likely have to change your file structure around.