# Next.js + Apollo + Mongodb : Unable to have acces to Apollo context in SSR mode

Tags: mongodb, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, apollo-server

i am triying to connect MongoDB with the NextJS API route Apollo example:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-apollo-server-and-client

I cannot find any official doc. So i follow this topic:
[Connect Apollo with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459747/connect-apollo-with-mongodb)
The idea is to connect Mongodb from the context of ApolloServer

pages/api/graphql.js

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import { schema } from '../../apollo/schema';
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../utils/mongodb';

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async () => {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
    return { db };
  },
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' });
```

the "connectToDatabase" is coming from the example "with-mongo"
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/util/mongodb.js

There is 3 ways of rendering pages in NextJS. When i connect my db like so (inside the ApolloServer context) it works just fine with the client side rendering but not at all with the Static and Server Side Rendering. The context inside my resolver function is undefined.

apollo/resolvers.js

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {

    async getAllCards(_parent, _args, _context, _info) {
      console.log('_context resolver :>> ', _context);

      const res = await _context.db.db
        .collection('cards')
        .find({})
        .limit(20)
        .toArray();

      console.log('res :>> ', res);

      return res;
    },
  },
};
```

At that point i tried to follow this topic
[Next.js graphql context is empty {} on SSR getServerSideProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537328/next-js-graphql-context-is-empty-on-ssr-getserversideprops)

Following thoses steps i am ending with 2 files modified:

pages/api/graphql

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import { schema } from '../../apollo/schema';
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../utils/mongodb';

async function contextResolver(ctx) {
  ctx.db = await connectToDatabase();

  return ctx;
}

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: contextResolver,
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' });
```

and

pages/explore_SSR.js

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { initializeApollo } from '../apollo/client';
import { connectToDatabase } from '../utils/mongodb';


const Explore = () => {
 
return (
 // UI Stuff
 )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  console.log('ctx :>> ', ctx);
  async function contextResolver(ctx) {
    ctx.db = await connectToDatabase();
    return ctx;
  }
  await contextResolver(ctx);
  console.log('ctx after :>> ', ctx);

  const apolloClient = initializeApollo(null, ctx);

  await apolloClient.query({
    query: gql`
      query GetAllMementoQuery {
        getAllMemento {
          title
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      props: { initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract() },
    },
  };
}

export default Explore;
```

result of the console.log: console.log('ctx after :>> ', ctx);

```
ctx after :>>  {
  req: IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: true,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: clearRequestTimeout] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [ServerResponse],
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 285916,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idleStart: 24100466,
        _onTimeout: null,
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: true,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 290206,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 290203
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: true,
    headers: {
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',
      accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
      'accept-language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      referer: 'http://localhost:3000/explore_clientSide',
      dnt: '1',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
      'sec-gpc': '1'
    },
    rawHeaders: [
      'Host',
      'localhost:3000',
      'User-Agent',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',
      'Accept',
      'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Language',
      'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding',
      'gzip, deflate',
      'Referer',
      'http://localhost:3000/explore_clientSide',
      'DNT',
      '1',
      'Connection',
      'keep-alive',
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests',
      '1',
      'Sec-GPC',
      '1'
    ],
    trailers: {},
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '/explore_SSR',
    method: 'GET',
    statusCode: null,
    statusMessage: null,
    client: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [ServerResponse],
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 285916,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idleStart: 24100466,
        _onTimeout: null,
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: true,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 290206,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 290203
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _consuming: false,
    _dumped: false,
    cookies: [Getter/Setter],
    __NEXT_INIT_QUERY: {},
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  res: <ref *1> ServerResponse {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: true,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: false,
    _headerSent: false,
    socket: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 285916,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idleStart: 24100466,
        _onTimeout: null,
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: true,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 290206,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 290203
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: null,
    _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
    _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
    _sent100: false,
    _expect_continue: false,
    statusCode: 200,
    flush: [Function: flush],
    write: [Function: write],
    end: [Function: end],
    on: [Function: on],
    writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: null
  },
  query: {},
  resolvedUrl: '/explore_SSR',
  locales: undefined,
  locale: undefined,
  defaultLocale: undefined,
  db: {
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      topology: [NativeTopology],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    db: Db {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      serverConfig: [Getter],
      bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
      databaseName: [Getter],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  }
}
```

But it's not working for me. The _context of my resolver is still undefined.
(console.log in apollo/resolvers.js: _context  :>>  undefined)

Maybe we cannot use Apollo and Database connection with the API route and Server side rendering mode or i just missing something big.

Any idea of how i could implement the Mongodb database connection to have acces to it from my resolver in any kind of rendering mode?

Comment: result of console.log ctx after  `contextResolver(ctx);` ?

Comment: I have updated my post. So the db is added to the ctx. But its not send to the resolver.